# How To Optimise Daedalus Syncing?

Tags: cardano-cli, cardano-node, daedalus, node

So I started using my Daedalus Node as the node (instead of the direct build) for the cardano-cli, but it always takes forever to sync and I am wondering if I misconfigured something or if there's a better setup.

Can you please share your Daedalus optimisations/Configs?

Thanks

Comment: To help others with a similar issue, can you list for system specs and the time it has taken so far. It would be good to know your RAM size, SSD or HDD, and network speed via fast.com or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Erik mentioned, Daedalus is a full node and thus requires downloading the chain from peers and validating it locally on your machine. **However, if you already have a trusted copy of the chain (either from previously syncing a full node or some other source), you can manually copy it into Daedalus' state directory.** Doing this will speed things up because Daedalus will only have to validate the provided chain instead of downloading the whole thing from genesis. Of course, it will also have to download whatever is needed to extend the provided chain's tip to the current tip.

First, launch Daedalus, and click on Help > Daedalus Diagnostics. Under the "Core Info" section, the "Daedalus State Directory" specifies the filepath that Daedalus uses on your computer. In this directory should be a folder titled `chain`, containing 3 subdirectories: `immutable`, `ledger`, and `volatile`, as well as 2 files: `lock` and `protocolMagicId`.

Next, shutdown Daedalus, then replace the 5 assets in the `chain` folder with the other 5 found in your local copy of the chain (they should all have the same filenames as mentioned above). Also, make sure the `chain` folder and files have appropriate permissions (chmod 775 for `chain`).

Restart Daedalus and enjoy a faster sync!

Comment: Man your Daedalus knowledge is impressive you seem to be answering all my questions. A well-deserved upvote and tick.

Answer (score 1):

Define "forever".

Sorry, but there are no tweaks to make it faster. If there were, they would be the default.

Please remember that Daedalus is a "full node". That means it downloads and stores the complete blockchain history, which on my full synced Linux machine uses disk store of 67 Gig for mainnet. I have not done a full sync with Daedalus recently, but I suspect it would be about 24 hours to sync.

There are however some thing that might help, like use a recent machine with at last 16G of RAM, use an SSD disk (which is faster than the older electro-mechanical ones, have a decent network connection.